# Extract the number of ID in a list of text and return the next cell fpr each one

Tags: excel

I am stuck with excel. 
I have a list of text with an unknow number of ID:

```
'C7, C1, C9, C13
```

And in another  tab have a list:

[image: List equivalent]

I want to return the equivalent of 'C7, C1, C9, C13 with the corresponding value. 
[Result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2y4V.png)
This would give: 'QKUUOEUY, GDXVXIYL, CUPPIXHF, CKMUAFGG

How can I do this?
First I need to find how many ID I have in my list using `=NBCAR(A2)-NBCAR(SUBSTITUE(A2;CAR(44);"")) + 1`, 
I also able to find one equivalent using XLOOKUP but I need to take each ID one by one to return the value and I have no idea how to do so.

Thank  you for the help

Comment: Do you have access to the TEXTJOIN formula?

Comment: Yes I can but it's the quivalent a CONCAT ofrmula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a similar case.  I am using Excel 365.  The comma-separated list in in **A1** and the lookup table is in columns **B** and **C**:

[image]

In **D1** enter:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,VLOOKUP(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,",",REPT(" ",999)),SEQUENCE(1+LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")))*999-998,999)),B1:C13,2,FALSE))
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

The core of the formula `TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,",",REPT(" ",999)),SEQUENCE(1+LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")))*999-998,999))` parses the comma-separated list and produces a spill-down.

The `VLOOKUP()` retrieves the data items from column **C**.

The `TEXTJOIN()` concatenates the list of **C** items.

Comment: Woaw thank you I am gonna try this.
Question, what is the 999 and 999-998,999 are used for?
I am currently struggling with the annoying translate french -nglish function with excel, for whatever reason they replace comma with semicolon...

Comment: @AlexDana  The big integers facilitate changing the comma-separated string into a massively padded space-separated string which is then cut into chunks by `MID()` ............................if you have problems with the formula I will give you a VBA UDF.

Comment: @AlexDana  I will look into it.................check back later.......................

Comment: Thank you Gary, I finally made it ;O

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `TEXTJOIN` and `FILTERXML` functions, you can use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,$A$1:$B$13)&"</s></t>",
"//s[.='" & TEXTJOIN("' or .='",TRUE,FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(C1,",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s"))& "']/following::*[1]"))
```

**Algorithm**

- Create an XML from the LookupTable, using `TEXTJOIN` to separate each node

  - The nodes will be created in pairs like `C1`, `Value`
- Create another XML separating the lookup values into separate nodes, and concatenating things together to create an xPath argument that looks like:

[image]

- That argument says to find a node that contains any of the tokens, and return the next following node, which would be the value.
- **Note**: The formula is case sensitive. If you need it to be case-insensitive, you can translate the case as needed.

[image]